# Randomly place images in multiple Image controls

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a simple "Pairs" game in WPF. I have 12 Image controls on MainWindow. What I need to do, is to use OpenFileDialog to select multiple Images (can be less then all 6) and then randomly place them into Image controls. Each picture should appear twice. How would I be able to achieve this? I am stuck here for a while and only have following code at the moment. I am not asking for a solution, I only need a few pointers on how to deal with this. Thank you.

```
  > public ObservableCollection<Image> GetImages()
    {
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.Multiselect = true;

        ObservableCollection<Image> imagesList = new ObservableCollection<Image>();

        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            foreach (String img in dlg.FileNames)
            {
                Image image = new Image();

                image.Name = "";
                image.Location = img;
                imagesList.Add(image);
            }
        }
        return imagesList;
    }
```

Comment: Basic idea: Take the filenames from the dialog and put them twice(!) into a list (let's call it *fileList*). Now run a loop generating the images. In the loop, generate a random number in the range of 0 to *fileList.Count-1*. Get the respective filename element from *fileList* to create the Image, and also remove that element from the *fileList*. The loop finishes when *fileList* becomes empty.

Comment: Will try it out. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve your required results. A good way would be to use the [`Directory.GetFiles` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which will return a collection of `string` file paths:

```
string [] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
```

You can then use a method to randomise the order of the collection. From the [C# Shuffle Array](http://www.dotnetperls.com/shuffle) page on DotNETPerls:

```
public string[] RandomizeStrings(string[] arr)
{
    List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
    // Add all strings from array
    // Add new random int each time
    foreach (string s in arr)
    {
        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(_random.Next(), s));
    }
    // Sort the list by the random number
    var sorted = from item in list
             orderby item.Key
             select item;
    // Allocate new string array
    string[] result = new string[arr.Length];
    // Copy values to array
    int index = 0;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> pair in sorted)
    {
        result[index] = pair.Value;
        index++;
    }
    // Return copied array
    return result;
}
```

Then add your duplicate file paths, re-randomise the order again and populate your UI property with the items:

```
string[] filePathsToUse = new string[filePaths.Length * 2];
filePaths = RandomizeStrings(filePaths);
for (int count = 0; count < yourRequiredNumber; count++)
{
    filePathsToUse.Add(filePaths(count));
    filePathsToUse.Add(filePaths(count));
}
// Finally, randomize the collection again:
ObservableCollection<string> filePathsToBindTo = new 
    ObservableCollection<string>(RandomizeStrings(filePathsToUse));
```

Of course, you could also do it in many other ways, some easier to understand, some more efficient. Just pick a method that you feel comfortable with.